# Protetor de Links em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Ola gostaria de saber como posso alterar o código abaixo de proteção de links da seguinte forma preciso que no caso ele libere o link de download caso clique em alguma área de publicidade dentro de uma DIV e que tenha como aplicar essa função em varias div através do uso de ID.

Preciso também que apareça uma mensagem assim "Link sendo gerado aguarde **tempo** ou clique em uma das publicidades para liberar o link"

**Obs:** Tempo e onde aparecera o contagem.

De forma que use ID nelas para identificar as DIV's  que tiverem as propagandas e ao serem clicadas seja liberado o link de Download o código que eu tenho só aplica um cronometro mais não libera o links, alguem pode me ajudar ?

```
<script>
var tempo = 10;

window.onload = function () { 
  contagem();
} 

function contagem() {
 if(tempo>0) {
  var span = document.getElementById('tempo_espera');
  span.innerHTML = tempo;
  tempo--;
  setTimeout("contagem()",1000);
 }
 else {
var div = document.getElementById('subs'); 

    div.innerHTML = '<a id="down" href="downloads.php?protetorpage=multiplo_download&tipo=video&action=download&id=2&url=url"><b>BAIXAR</b><br />PELO MEDIAFIRE</a>';

 }
}
</script>
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar com isso ?

Comment: Quando dizes _"caso clique em alguma área de publicidade"_, essa publicidade está dentro de iFrames?